# Rails 2.3.8 How is 'id' passed to method in pagination example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, pagination

I'm working through "Learning Rails by Example" tutorial by Michael Hartl(11.33).The relevant code is:

---

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home

    @title = "Home"
    if signed_in?
      @micropost = Micropost.new
       @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
  end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def feed

    Micropost.all(:conditions => ["user_id = ?", id])

  end
```

---

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)

    user.remember_me!
    cookies[:remember_token] = { :value   => user.remember_token,
                                 :expires => 20.years.from_now.utc }
    self.current_user= user
  end

  def current_user=(user)

    @current_user = user
  end


  def current_user

    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end
```

---

@feed_items is then rendered as a collection to "will_paginate" and everything works fine.

My problem is that I cannot understand how the current_user is passed to the "feed" method in the PagesController line ie

"@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])"

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_user` is never "passed" to the `feed` method - the `feed` method is **called** on the `current_user` object. Take a look at the User model:

```
def feed
  Micropost.all(:conditions => ["user_id = ?", id])
end
```

This is an instance method which is executed when you call `current_user.feed`. The `id` in the `:conditions` hash refers to the `id` of the user object instance, in this case `current_user`.

Comment: StefanO
Thank you so much, its obvious when you explain it
I thought current_user had to be an object to do a method call
But further reading shows it can be a variable
I have not realized this before
Is it common? could you point me to any examples?
Cheers
Alan

Comment: In Ruby, everything is an object, even things which are primitive types in other languages, like integers. So, for example, you can have the following objects:
1 - the number one;
1.month - the timespan one month;
1.month.ago - the datetime corresponding to exactly one month before now.

This is quite different from most other languages which I've used. You can read more about the basics here http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/

Comment: StefanO
Thanks again, a timely reminder for me to review Ruby basics
Alan

Answer (score 0):

Most likely "current_user" is defined in the paret class of your controller: ApplicationController. Search for "application_controller.rb" in your controller directory.

Comment: Current_user is shown above in SessionsHelper and will return say 44 but how does this get passed to the "feed" method ??
Alan